# Searching for resources for partners of counterdependant people

Tags: personality-disorder

so I started dating a girl who has slight counterdependency issues. She is already in therapy for a while and is working on the matter, but I struggle to find any useful material that will guide me as the partner.

What I mean by "guide":
I have a relative with a borderline disorder and similar "guides" helped me a lot both to understand and support him, so I thought maybe there is smth similar out there for counterdependency.

Will appreciate your suggestions, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the benefit of those who don't know, [counter-dependency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counterdependency) is the state of refusal of attachment, the denial of personal need and dependency.

I did a quick search and *The Flight from Intimacy* by Barry Weinhold, a licensed Psychologist, and Janae Weinhold, a Professional Counselor:

> shows readers how to recognize and cope with counter-dependent people. And if you recognize yourself in the description above, this book will help you learn how to change. It teaches readers how to use committed relationships to heal childhood wounds and provides proven ways to use conflicts as opportunities for creating intimate, partnership relationships.

Looking at a preview in Amazon, the book seems to be full of reference citations, which is not common in self-help books.

### References

Weinhold, J. B., & Weinhold, B. K. (2008). *The flight from intimacy: Healing your relationship of counter-dependency-the other side of co-dependency*. Novato, CA: New World Library. ISBN: 978-1-57731-605-3